# React Native -- How to update Flatlist based on data coming from API

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, api, react-native-flatlist

I have developed a functionality in which I am asking user to add emails as comma separated in TextInput and when user submit then I split the string and send string one by one to hit the API. And when I get response from API I add that particular string into array and hit api again with next string but issue is that my FlatList update only first item in the list. Its not updating the next time.

// Call API to based

```
const setUpUSer = (email, token) => {
console.log('useer call');
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({
  email: email,
  channel: route.params.channel,
});
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: BASE_URL + SET_UP_USER,
  headers: {
    'x-jwt-token': token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  data: data,
};

axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));

    addUsersIntoList(email);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

// Add data into array

```
 const addUsersIntoList = user => {
console.log('add user', userArray);

for (let i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
 
  console.log('user array item', userArray[i]);
}

let newArray = [...userArray];

let obj = {userEmail: user};

newArray.push(obj);
setUserArray(newArray);
};
```

And now update FLatList based on data:

```
 <FlatList
      data={userArray}
      extraData={userArray}
      scrollEnabled={true}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <UserSetUpCard navigation={navigation} item={item} />
      )}
      numColumns={1}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      contentContainerStyle={{marginTop: height * 0.02}}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      style={{marginBottom: height * 0.02}}
      bounces={false}
    />
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using fetch function and setState without async approach, this may easily casue bugs. Application may use state which is not the latest one.

I would suggest using `Promise.all()` to fetch multiple API, and gather the result at once.

```
async function submit(){

  //Ready Email list and token
  let tempEmailArray = [
    "abc@abc.com",
    "def@def.com",
  ];
  let token = "abcdefg";

  const requestArray = await Promise.all(tempEmailArray.map((email) => {
    //Your Axios request config
    let config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: BASE_URL + SET_UP_USER,
      headers: {
        'x-jwt-token': token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        channel: route.params.channel,
      }),
    };

    return axios(config)
      .then((response) =>{
        return email;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return false;
      });
  }));

  let tempUserArray = [...userArray];
  requestArray.forEach(element => {
    //Check every elment in returned result
    if(element != false){
      tempUserArray.push({userEmail: element});
    }
    else{
      //error handling
    }
  })
  setUserArray(tempUserArray);
}
```